# Lifting of a morphism in a hom-functor when hom-sets are empty

Tags: category-theory, functors, hom-functor

I'm having trouble in unserstanding a hom-functor.

Suppose we have a hom-functor $\mathrm{Hom}(X,$_$)$ for some Category $\mathcal{C}$.

Suppose further that the hom-sets $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,A)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,B)$ are empty and there exists an arrow $f$ going from $A$ to $B$.

What would be the lifted function $\mathcal{C}(X,f)$ in category $\mathbf{Set}$?

Isn't this a function going from the empty set to the empty set?

How does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that the notation for the hom-set is $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, A)$, rather than $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X, A)$ (the $\mathbf{Set}$ is implicit).

Yes, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, f)$ will be a function $\emptyset \to \emptyset$ if $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, A)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, B)$ are empty. But that's okay! There is exactly one function from the empty set to the empty set, which is the identity function. (In fact, for each set $Y$, there's exactly one function from the empty set to $Y$. We just have to provide an assignment of each element in the domain to an element of the codomain: when the domain is empty, this is trivial, as there aren't any elements to provide assingments for.)